# Joining using || - No results

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, aginity

This is what I am currently joining:

```
INNER JOIN us_raw.l_dmw_order_report t1 on t2.channel_uid = t1.customer_id
```

However, I need it so that it's like this instead:

```
INNER JOIN us_raw.l_dmw_order_report t1 on t2.channel_uid = ('UNU' || t1.customer_id)
```

When I do that, it does not seem to pull what I need, so I'm wondering if there is another way to do what I'm trying to do. Basically, t1's customer_id is t2's channel_uid, except with a 'UNU' in front of it (yea, idk who created this table but apparently that's the only difference, and I spot-checked to confirm).

Please let me know if you need more information, working with a confidential DB.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you share samples of the `t2.channel_uid` and `t1.customer_id`?

Comment: @urdearboy hi, here is an example: channel_uid sample is UNUUS621111111463170
customer_id
US621111111463170, and this is the case for 80% of the data, so the only difference is the UNU in the beginning

Comment: So you want to create `t2.channel_uid` by concatenating the `UNU` prefix and value of the column `t1.customer_id`, am I right? I would try `...ON t2.channel_uid = CONCAT('UNU', t1.customer_id)`.

Comment: Also, please update your question with expected and actual behavior. What does "_does not seem to pull what I need_" exactly mean, what results are you getting and how is it different from the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it right, you want to construct the value of `t2.channel_uid` by concatenating the prefix `UNU` and the value of `t1.customer_id` column. If that's the case, the following should work:

```
INNER JOIN us_raw.l_dmw_order_report t1 on t2.channel_uid = CONCAT('UNU', t1.customer_id)
```

Depending on what data types of your columns, you may need some type casting.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the answer by forcing the join on a substring:

```
INNER JOIN l_act_account t2 ON customer_id = SUBSTRING(t2.channel_uid,4,18)
```

Instead of trying to add the characters, I just forced it to disregard in the table that had the characters lol